# FTP Task in SSIS package not executing

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, ftp, ssms

I have a stored procedure in SSMS that is triggered by a button on web form.
The stored procedure executes a batch file that contains the following:

DTEXEC /FILE "\\servername\E$\Export\TEST.dtsx"

The TEST.dtsx SSIS package simply queries a table in SSMS and creates a XML file that is first saved locally.  After the XML file is created, I have a FTP Task that sends it first to our FTP server, then another FTP Task that sends it to a remote FTP server.  Then finally i have a FTP task that deletes the original XML file created locally.  Here is a picture of how it's setup:

TEST SSIS Package:

[image]

If I run the SSIS Package manually through Visual Studio, everything works perfectly.  However if I manually kick off the stored procedure, the package only gets as far as creating the XML file, and does not execute any of the FTP Tasks.

I've tried setting my FTP Tasks to passive and have also tried to use 32-bit version of DTEXEC.

Any help on how I can get my FTP Tasks to run when using the stored procedure?
Thanks!

Comment: Please check/provide the Result/ Messages while you execute the procedure. It must have some information about the error breaking the package.

Comment: No errors in the Results or Messages.  Procedure executes successfully and returns (1 row affected) in the results which is correct.

Comment: maybe batch file run from within the procedure isn't giving the package execution outputs in the results tab; try executing the batch file from command line and see the output from there.

Comment: Might be procedure run under different sql user. And that user does not have permission for FTP to put file on remote. please verify permission stuff.

Comment: satishcse, I ran the batch file from command line (as admin) and received:

Error: 2018-09-10 13:25:19.72
   Code: 0xC001602A
   Source: TEST Connection manager "FTP Local"
   Description: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The password was not allowed
End Error

Comment: I've changed my Protection Level of the package to EncryptSensitiveWithPassword, and now I get a little bit of a different error when running the batch file from command line:

Error: 2018-09-10 15:24:18.03
   Code: 0xC001602A
   Source: TEST Connection manager "FTP Local"
   Description: An error occurred in the requested FTP operation. Detailed error description: The login request was denied
End Error